# personal.xlsb for excel 2016 doesn't update

Tags: excel, vba

folks,

i started using personal.xlsb for excel 2016 about a month ago. it holds vba code added for excel userforms. it stopped working a week ago. if i make a change to the vba code in the userform, i will be asked ...do you want to save to personal.xlsb..., i say yes, it saves [apparently virtually].
but the next time i try to execute the modified userform, the code change does not appear to have taken effect.
the personal.xlsb is in XLSTART, it is trusted, it is NOT found as 'disabled due to corruption'.
i have googled, but i see no remedy on the internet. anyone experience this before? [excel2016, 32bit version, 64bit w10, just started 1-2 weeks ago]

any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
ron

Comment: Does it prompt you to save the `personal.xlsb` workbook when exiting Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Citing a response from [Mr. Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/713347-macro-personal-xlsb-not-showing-available-macro.html):

> Unless I am mistaken, a Userform won't show up in the list, you have to call with a button or module... so just add

```
Sub OpenForm()
UserForm1.Show 'Change this to your UserForm name.
End Sub
```

> Should work for you...

Comment: yes, it asks do u want to save and it does save. i renamed, brought up excel, NO vba there so i know XLSTART is working, and yes, i have a macro 'button'. here is issue 1. i added new code 2. i entered the xls, and the user form reflects updt 3. i saved it into personal [it said ..do u want to save.. etc etc] 4. i save/close the xls, re-opened, the new code is not reflected. see anything i did wrong?

i think next step is to export personal before and after save to see what actually is happening. this is new though. it has been working as expected for months.